# Why do I get a " Invalid .internal.selfref detected" warning (but no output) even if I am not using list(),key<-, names<-, or attr<-?

Tags: r, data.table

In a new user created function I like to do some data.table transformations, especially I like to create a new column with the ':=' command.

Assume I like to make a new column called Sex that capitalizes the first letter of the column df$sex in my example data.frame df.

The output of my prepare function should be a data.table with the same name as before but with the additional "capitalised" column.

I try several ways to loop over the data.table. However I always get the following warning (and no correct output):

> Warning message:
>   In `[.data.table`(x, , `:=`(Sex, stringr::str_to_title(sex))) :
>     Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)


df <- data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), 
                      sex = c("m", "f"))
df %>%   setDT()
is.data.table(df)
```

This is the easiest way to write my function:

```
prepare1<-function(x){
x[,Sex:=stringr::str_to_title(sex)]
}
prepare1(df)
#--> WARNING. (as block quoted above)


prepare2<-function(x){
  x[, `:=`(Sex, stringr::str_to_title(sex))]
}
prepare2(df)
#--> WARNING. . (as block quoted above)


prepare3<-function(x){
  require(data.table)
  y <-as.data.table(list(x))
  y <- y[,Sex:=stringr::str_to_title(sex)]
  x <<- y
}
prepare3(df)
```

The last version does NOT throw the warning, but makes a new dataset called x. But I wanted to override the dataset I put in the function (if I have to go that way at all.)

From the [:= help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/%3A%3D) I also know I can use set, however I am not able to adapt the command appropriate. In case that could cure my problem I am happy to receive help on that, too! `set(x, i = NULL, Sex, str_to_title(sex))` is apparently wrong ...

Up on request/to make the discussion in the comments clearer I show how my code produces the problem

```
    library(data.table)
library(stringr)


df <- data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), 
                      sex = c("m", "f"))

GetLastAssigned <- function(match = "<- *data.frame",
                            remove = " *<-.*") {
  f <- tempfile()
  savehistory(f)
  history <- readLines(f)
  unlink(f)
  match <- grep(match, history, value = TRUE)
  get(sub(remove, "", match[length(match)]))
}

#ok, no need for magrittr
setDT(GetLastAssigned())

#check the last function worked
is.data.table(df)

prepare1<-function(x){
x[,Sex:=stringr::str_to_title(sex)]
}

prepare1(GetLastAssigned())
# I get a warning and it does not work.
prepare1(df)
# I get a warning and it does not work, either.


#If I manually type setDT(df) everything works fine but I cannot type the "right" dfs at all the places where I need to do this transformation.
```

Comment: The culprit appears to be `magrittr`. If you just do `setDT(df)` this works as intended.

Comment: If you look at the source of `\`%>%\`` you see quite a few functions that are good candidates for this kind of issues.

Comment: thank you. but I need the Magrittr as I am in my real application need not to set df through another function. I.e. "myotherfunction" returns df. But it needs to be "myotherfunction %>%   setDT() , or setDT(myotherfunction).

Comment: Well, you can try opening an issue on the data.table bug tracker. Personally, I see absolutely no need for using magrittr (and thus don't use it).

Comment: Dear Roland I usually also don't use the Magrittr but as setDT(Myotherfunction()) does not work to set the data.frame dt (recalled through "myotherfunction")) as a data.table I need a work-around. :( How can I see the source of `%>%`  ?

Comment: Just do `res <- Myotherfunction(); setDT(res)`. I really don't see the problem. You can see the source code by copying the code in my previous comment (including the backticks) into R.

Comment: But have an upvote. This is a very well written question with a nice reproducible example.

Comment: Dear Roland I did not know about the usage of the additional backpacks as well as the motherfunction, as I am very new to R. Thank you so much for your detailed advice (and the upvote, too). "Dankeschön!/Thanks a lot!"

Comment: I tried without magrittr but it still is not the solution. I still get these errors.

Comment: @Roland Not sure if it's the same issue, but I have run into related problems https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1628 which links to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26072152 where Arun in 2014 closed with "The idea so far is to use `setDT` to convert to data.tables before providing it to a function. But I'd like that these cases be resolved"

Comment: You might want to select a better title (click "edit" below the question to start), since the question has no mention of errors or "list()"

Comment: @Frank I changed the title. Thank you. However I am not really capable of understanding if it is really the same (for 5 years) unresolved problem. :( :/

Comment: @canIchangethis Yes, I am not sure if it is either. I guess the advice Arun gave then "to convert to data.tables before providing it to a function" is still the best way to go, if possible, though.

Comment: Well I can provide some more details, how I currently work. Will put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround along the OP's lines:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

GetLastAssigned2 <- function(match = "<- *data.frame", remove = " *<-.*") {
  f <- tempfile()
  savehistory(f)
  history <- readLines(f)
  unlink(f)
  match <- grep(match, history, value = TRUE)
  nm <- sub(remove, "", match[length(match)])
  list(nm = as.name(nm), addr = address(get(nm)))
}

prepit <- function(x){
  x[,Sex:=stringr::str_to_title(sex)]
}

# usage
df <- data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), sex = c("m", "f"))
z <- GetLastAssigned2()
eval(substitute(setDT(x), list(x=z$nm)))

str(df) # it seemingly works, since there is a selfref

# usage 2
df <- data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), sex = c("m", "f"))
setDT(df)
prepit(df)
str(df) # works

# usage 3
df <- data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), sex = c("m", "f"))
z <- GetLastAssigned2()
eval(substitute(setDT(x), list(x=z$nm)))
eval(substitute(prepit(x), list(x=z$nm)))
str(df) # works
```

Some big caveats:

- `savehistory` is only effective in interactive use, based on my reading of the docs
- using regex on human input (code typed in interactively) is complicated and risky
- even this workaround will fail if data.table `x` passed to prepit is not sufficiently "[pre-allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490985)" space for extra columns

The data.table interface is based on passing the name/symbol of the data.frame or data.table, rather than the value (which is what `get` provides), as [explained by Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26072152) one of the data.table authors. Note that the address cannot be passed around either. `z$address` soon fails to match `address(df)` in all examples above.

---

> If I manually type setDT(df) everything works fine but I cannot type the "right" dfs at all the places where I need to do this transformation.

One idea:

```
# helper to compose expressions
subit = function(cmd, df_nm) 
  do.call("substitute", list(cmd, list(x=as.name(df_nm))))

# list of expressions with x where the df name belongs
my_cmds = list(
  setDT  = quote(setDT(x)),
  prepit = quote(x[,Sex:=stringr::str_to_title(sex)])
)

# usage 4
df = data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), sex = c("m", "f"))
df_nm = "df" # somehow get this... hopefully not via regex of command history
eval(subit(my_cmds$setDT, df_nm))
eval(subit(my_cmds$prepit, df_nm))

# usage 5
df = data.frame("age" = c(17, 04), sex = c("m", "f"))
df_nm = "df" 
for(ex in lapply(my_cmds, subit, df_nm = df_nm)) eval(ex)
```

I think this is more aligned with recommended programmatic usage of data.table.

There is probably some way to wrap this in a function by altering the `envir=` argument to `eval()` but I'm not knowledgeable about that.

Regarding how to get the name of the assignment target in `nm <- data.frame(...)`, it looks like there are no good options. Maybe see [How do I access the name of the variable assigned to the result of a function within the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46204937) or [Get name of x when defining `(<-` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246432/get-name-of-x-when-defining-operator)

Comment: If your R code doesn't know the name of an object, you simply have designed it badly. I can't think of a valid reason to need arbitrary object names.

Comment: Dear Frank, thanks a lot, I will check this out. Dear Roland, well if I perform the prepare(x) command on 28 datasets (x) I do not always want to put the names of the datasets. this is why I think I need arbitrary object names. I really wonder why this is so a "non-issue" for you?

Comment: Frank, well the whole "df_nm = "df" # somehow get this... hopefully not via regex of command history" part after the # is confusing, as I never came across any other way to get this stuf. But besides that, interesting approach. I still need more time to completely understand the code. I am very new to R.